# pycharm startup error: The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of D:\Java jdk17.0.6) does not point to a valid JVM installation

Tags: pycharm, java-home

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHUle.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oYrf.png)
I installed pycharm and when I started it I got the error popup described above. I made sure that the JAVA_HOME variable was not written incorrectly, and I added it to the PATH environment variable, but the above problem still occurred.

However, when I tried to disable the third-party plug-ins GitHub copilot and bito, this error disappeared. After that, I started those two plug-ins again, and the error pop-up window still did not appear. I'm totally confused